# wp.customize is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've been developing my own theme on a Mutlisite and one of the test sites I'm working on using a default theme I'm building is outputting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: wp.customize is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (customizer.js?ver=4.9.5:3)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

My functions.php has these functions included:

```
<?php

// Include Theme Customizer Settings
require_once('includes/customizer.php');

//


// MEDIA LIBRARY QUEUE
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_javascript', 100);
function my_register_javascript() {
  wp_register_script('mediaelement', plugins_url('wp-mediaelement.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '4.8.2', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('mediaelement');
}

// REQUIRE BS MENU
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';

// REGISTER MAIN MENU LOCATION
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('main-menu',__( 'Main Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

// ADD LOGO SUPPORT TO THEME
function pb_custom_logo() {
  add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pb_custom_logo' );
function theme_prefix_the_custom_logo() {
    if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    }
}


// Add thumbnail support to posts
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

// Create Services Post Type
function services_posttype() {

  register_post_type( 'Services',
  // CPT Options
      array(
          'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Services' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Service' )
          ),
          'public' => true,
          'has_archive' => true,
          'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'services'),
      )
  );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'services_posttype' );



?>
```

Customizer.php:

```
<?php

function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/customizer.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );

add_action( 'customize_register', 'pb_customizer_settings' );
function pb_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ) {


    //
    // MAIN HOME BANNER
    //

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'pb_front_page_banner' , array(
        'title'      => 'Front Page Banner',
        'priority'   => 30,
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'banner_image' , array(
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customize,'banner_image',array(
                'label' => 'Banner Image',
                'section' => 'pb_front_page_banner',
                'settings' => 'banner_image',
                'priority' => 2,
                'description' => 'This will change your photo on the main header of the front page.',
            )
        )
    );

    // BANNER TITLE

    $wp_customize->add_setting('banner_title', array(
        'default'     => 'This is the main header content.',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'banner_title', array(
        'label'     => 'Banner Title',
        'section'   => 'pb_front_page_banner',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'description' => 'This is the main title on the banner.',
    ));

    // BANNER PARAGRAPH 

    $wp_customize->add_setting('banner_para', array(
        'default'     => 'This is the main content which will be displayed in a paragraph.',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'banner_para', array(
        'label'     => 'Banner Paragraph',
        'section'   => 'pb_front_page_banner',
        'type'      => 'textarea',
        'description' => 'This is the text under the main title on the banner.',
    ));

    /////////////////////
    // CONTACT DETAILS //
    /////////////////////

    // Create the section
    $wp_customize->add_section('pb_foot_contact' , array(
        'title'      => 'Contact Details',
        'priority'   => 30,
    ));

    //Telephone

    $wp_customize->add_setting('contact_det_tel', array(
        'default'     => '',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('contact_det_tel', array(
        'label'     => 'Telephone Number',
        'section'   => 'pb_foot_contact',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'description' => 'This will display your telephone number so customers can call you.',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'placeholder' => __('e.g 0151 123 4567'),
        )
    ));

    //Email Address

    $wp_customize->add_setting('contact_det_email', array(
        'default'     => '',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('contact_det_email', array(
        'label'     => 'E-Mail Address',
        'section'   => 'pb_foot_contact',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'description' => 'This will show customers what E-Mail Address you can be contacted on.',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'placeholder' => __( 'e.g info@powerbookings.com'),
        )
    ));

    //Company Address

    $wp_customize->add_setting('contact_det_address', array(
        'default'     => '',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('contact_det_address', array(
        'label'     => 'Company Address',
        'section'   => 'pb_foot_contact',
        'type'      => 'textarea',
        'description' => 'This will display your trading address to your customers. Create a new line by typing <code>&lt;br&gt;</code>. ',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'placeholder' => __('Company Address'),
        )
    ));

    //Company Address

    $wp_customize->add_setting('contact_det_opening', array(
        'default'     => '',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('contact_det_opening', array(
        'label'     => 'Opening Hours',
        'section'   => 'pb_foot_contact',
        'type'      => 'textarea',
        'description' => 'Show your customers what times you are open, and when you are closed. Create a new line by typing <code>&lt;br&gt;</code>.',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'placeholder' => __('Opening Hours'),
        )
    ));


}
?>
```

Customizer.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

    wp.customize( 'banner_title', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
          $( '.mi-content h1' ).html( newval );
        } );
      } );

    wp.customize( 'banner_para', function( value ) {
      value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $( '.mi-content p' ).html( newval );
      } );
    } );

    wp.customize('contact_det_tel', function(value) {
      console.log("postMessage");
      value.bind(function(newval) {
        $('.contact_det_tel').html(newval);
      } );
    });
    wp.customize('contact_det_email', function(value) {
      value.bind(function(newval) {
        $('.contact_det_email').html(newval);
      } );
    });
    wp.customize('contact_det_address', function(value) {
      value.bind(function(newval) {
        $('.contact_det_address').html(newval);
      } );
    });
    wp.customize('contact_det_opening', function(value) {
      value.bind(function(newval) {
        $('.contact_det_opening').html(newval);
      } );
    });



});
```

Now it seems that the functions work when I edit the site using the WordPress customizer but when I view the site on the front end it gets the first message.

I'm assuming I'm linking the files somewhere else in the theme but I can't seem to grasp where, or how it's being included. The file in question is the customize.js so I just need to figure out what it is that's causing it.

That's all the information that I think is relevant to this, if someone has a solution I would be grateful if they could help me.

Many thanks

Comment: you should add `Customizer.js` in footer.php

Comment: Hi @George I have tried it but still issues the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem... :/

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue recently, and tried a number of things to solve the issue, including moving my hook out of `functions.php` and into, my customiser.php itself.

> I managed to solve it by adjusting the following thanks to the [WP
>   Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Step_3:_Enqueue_Your_JavaScript);

```
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'theme_preview_register' );
function theme_preview_register() {
    // Customizer JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 
       'wpa-customizer', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/wpa-customizer.js', 
        array( 'jquery','customize-preview' ), // <<< Specify Dependencies...
        true );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Matty Clarke, you should enqueue your script in `customize_preview_init` hook.
i.e. This line
`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );`
becomes
`add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );`

Comment: why is that the case?

Comment: @niklas Because `wp_enqueue_scripts` loads script to the front end of the site, not to preview window. So it needs to be loaded in `customize_preview_init` instead. In preview mode, front end of the site is displayed in an iframe